# Opening picture from storage, why it returns FileNotFoundException?

Tags: android, imageview, bitmapfactory

I would like to open image from storage in imageView and I have this error:

Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1A10-2F0F/Pictures/photo.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

How can I open picture in imageView?

My code:

```
ImageView img;


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

OneClick to button opening ImageCapture:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "photo.jpg");

    Uri photoPath = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

OnCreate:

```
...
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
...
```

I have added in AndroidMainfest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if your file is really existing on your external storage, then check in your code if the path you are passing in argument is correct (pointing to something real or not)

Comment: App save picture in /storage/1A10-2F0F/Pictures/photo.jpg but in storage i havn't this folder. Why "1A10-2F0F" don't exist?

Comment: Then work on your saving/storing picture method, and after that you should be able to retrieve it and decode it into a bitmap

Comment: I replace this:imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "photo.jpg")  to this : imageFile=new File("/storage/Pictures/photo.jpg");  And when I try to accept captured image,  app crashed.

Comment: Now my path to file looks like this and on the storage exists picture but imageView don't display picture.         File imageFile= new File("/sdcard/pictures/","photo.jpg"); Unfortunately I have the same error